# Rounding double to 2 decimal places in an xml file with databinding

Tags: xml, android-studio, rounding, android-databinding, android-mvvm

```xml
<TextView
    android:text="@{'£' + String.valueOf(cartItem.product.price * cartItem.quantity)}" />
```

I'd like to know how to round numbers to two decimal places within an XML file which gets data via databinding. The above code is a part of what I currently have and works correctly as intended. This is a cart item and is displayed in a recycler view.

CartItem is a model. cartItem is a variable in the databinding layout of type CartItem in the xml file. Product is a model which is initialised as a variable within cartItem as product.

cartItem.product.price is a double
cartItem.quantity is an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by creating a private String total; inside CartItem

Created getter and setter for total

In the getter:

```java
public String getTotal() {
        return String.format("%.2f", quantity*product.getPrice());
    }
```

then went to the xml file and simply put in the string total instead of doing the calculation inside of the xml file.

```xml
<TextView
    android:text="@{'£' + cartItem.total}" />
```